# How to use distinct in following query

Tags: oracle9i

## CODE

```
SELECT            T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_EMPID, T_LEAVETYPE_MS.I_LEAVETYPE, T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_ALLOTTEDDAYS AS OPENINGBALANCE, EXTRACT(DAY
FROM T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_REQDATE) AS Dates, T_APPROVAL.I_CATEGORYNAME, T_LEAVEAPPLY.NOD,
T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LASTUPDATED, T_EMPLOYEE_MS.I_EMPNAME 
FROM              T_LEAVEAPPLY 
INNER JOIN        T_APPROVAL ON T_APPROVAL.I_EMPID = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_EMPID AND T_APPROVAL.I_REQDATE = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_REQDATE AND T_APPROVAL.I_APPROVALSTATUS = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_STATUS 
INNER JOIN        T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS ON T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_EMPID = T_APPROVAL.I_EMPID AND T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_EMPID = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_EMPID AND T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LEAVETYPEID = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_LEAVETYPEID
INNER JOIN        T_LEAVETYPE_MS ON T_LEAVETYPE_MS.I_LEAVETYPEID = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_LEAVETYPEID AND T_LEAVETYPE_MS.I_LEAVETYPEID = T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LEAVETYPEID
INNER JOIN        T_EMPLOYEE_MS ON T_EMPLOYEE_MS.I_EMPID = T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_EMPID
WHERE            (T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_EMPID = '9') AND (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM  T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LASTUPDATED) = '3') AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LASTUPDATED) = '2012') AND (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM   T_APPROVAL.I_REQDATE) = '3') AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T_APPROVAL.I_REQDATE) = '2012') AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T_LEAVEALLOCATION_MS.I_LASTUPDATED) = '2012')
ORDER BY T_LEAVEAPPLY.I_REQDATE DESC
```

## OUTPUT

#

9      Earn Leave         10          28       LEAVE    2    3/9/2012

9      Sick Leave         8               19       LEAVE    2    3/9/2012

9      Casual Leave      10               17       LEAVE    1    3/9/2012

9      Casual Leave      10               2            LEAVE    2    3/9/2012

#

Comment: This is just a wall of text... Firstly, can you please attempt to format your query in a readable manner. Secondly, what do you mean? What problems are you having? Why can't you just use the DISTINCT keyword?

Comment: sorry ben. please wait. when i'm using distinct, i'm getting error as invalid identifier even it is correct columns.

Comment: perhaps it could be interesting in cases like these, that you link to an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't ORDER BY I_REQDATE if you are not including it in the SELECT DISTINCT clause.